# Uncaught syntax error - Unexpected identifier Underscore.min.js line 24

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am getting uncaught syntax error

> unexpected identifier - underscore.min.js 24.

The error was appearing once I add this checkbox code in the template:

```
template: _.template('<h3>'+'<input type=checkbox'+'<% if(status === "complete") print("checked") %> />' + '<% = name %></h3>'),
```

I guess the error is in the checkbox code of the template and I can't figure out what that is.

Here is my code below :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>

</body>

<script>

var Friend = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var friend = new Friend ({ name:'phani'});

var FriendView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:'body',
    tagName:'article',
    id:'my-friend',
    className:'hello-friend',

    //template
    template: _.template('<h3>'+'<input type=checkbox'+'<% if(status === "complete") print("checked") %> />' + '<% = name %></h3>'),

    //event
    events:{
    "click h3":"alertStatus"
    },

    alertStatus: function(e){
        alert("Hey you clicked the h3!");
        },

    render:function(){
    var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
    $(this.el).html(this.template(attributes));
    }

});

var friendView = new FriendView({model:friend});
friendView.render();
console.log(friendView.el);

</script>
```

Comment: Where is `status` defined` ? I'd suggest adding a `debugger` statement to your template: http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1837

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the origin of the error, but in the line

```
template: _.template('<h3>'+'<input type=checkbox'+'<% if(status === "complete") print("checked") %> />' + '<% = name %></h3>'),
```

you should probably have a space before "checked", otherwise you will end up with something like

```
<input type=checkboxchecked />
```

By the way, you should have double quotes around `checkbox` too.

Comment: yeah that solves my problem of the checkbox not getting checked at first. But the error was actually because of not wrapping the print function like this {%> .... >%}. Thanks...